# Spring (boot) + Angular (2|4) authentication options

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm about to implement user authentication in my app.

Since it is my first Angular + Spring project i would like to know what are the possible options for authentication. I don't wait for detailed instructions, concept level is enough, so that i know where to dig.

I consider two ways of further back-end app development:

1. REST like;
2. regular spring MVC, however i don't know how to combine angular and spring in this case. Any suggestions in this regard are also appreciated.

Comment: I am just about to start applying this to my SpringMVC application as well. You could use jwt -> https://jwt.io/ Here are some libraries I have come across for jwt  https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt You're building an API for Angular?

Comment: This question can be answered by looking through the spring security reference documentation. (If you don't understand the docs, ask specific questions about what you don't understand.)

Comment: @user5500750 thanks for info! probably i will go with REST api for Angular, since i couldn't find any information how can Angular interact with spring in non REST way.

Comment: @meriton I don't think there is a documentation for authenticating users via API in SpringMVC official documentation or tutorials. If there is then you should have provided a link. Clearly that's what the OP wants. I think the question is valid. The OP wants a list of possible options and I have provided 1; jwt. I think you're referring to this; https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ I don't think this is a good documentation for API based authentication.

Comment: @user5500750 I've heard that jwt has drawbacks, one of them is impossibility to block user until his jwt token is expired, which is pretty important in my case. did i understand this correctly?

Comment: Ah, ok. Since the question was tagged spring-security, I had assumed that OP had already decided on a spring security solution, in which case it would have been odd not to read the docs first.

Comment: You can decided to invalidate the token whenever you want so any further requests are not accepted. Each time a request made the token will have to be validated first. You could refresh the token every so often and pass it to the client.

Comment: @user5500750 i see. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to accomplish this. The general idea is that the angular clients adds a credential to every request (typically in the authorization header) which a servlet Filter on the backend verifies before executing the request.

There are various standard ways to accomplish this, ranging from simple [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (which spring security can do easily) to full fledged single sign on protocols like OAuth 2 (and its extension [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/)).

> I've heard that jwt has drawbacks, one of them is impossibility to block user until his jwt token is expired, which is pretty important in my case

Not necessarily. [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is a standard for authentication, not access control. That is, it simply describes a way to identify users, but does not constrain how you make access control decisions. In particular, it is entirely possible that an authorization framework will load user permissions for every request, though doing so may not be its default configuration.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you.